# Implementing a list C

Tags: c

I have the code with the structure of a list and the code that implements it.

Structure,entry_t is the type of data on the list:

```
    #ifndef _list_private_h
    #define _list_private_h

    typedef struct list_t{
        struct node_t *head;
        int size;
    };

    typedef struct node_t{
        struct entry_t *element;
        struct node_t *next;
    }node_t;

    #endif
```

Code:

```
struct list_t *list_create(){
        struct list_t *list = (struct list_t*) malloc(sizeof(struct list_t));
        list->head=NULL;
        list->size=0;
        return list;
}

int list_destroy(struct list_t *list){
        node_t *no = list->head;
        while(no!=NULL){
              node_t *aux=no;
              entry_destroy(no->element);
              no=no->next;              
              free(aux);        
              list->size=(list->size)-1;                
        }
        free(list);
        return 0;
 }

 int list_add(struct list_t *list, struct entry_t *entry){
        node_t *no = list->head;
        if(no==NULL){
             list->head=(node_t*) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
             list->head->element=entry_dup(entry);
             list->size=list->size+1;   
             return 0;
        }
        else{
             while(no!=NULL){
                     no=no->next;
             }
             no=(node_t*) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
             no->element=entry_dup(entry);
             list->size=list->size+1;   
             return 0;
         }
         return -1;
  }           


 struct entry_t *list_get(struct list_t *list, char *key){
        node_t *no = list->head;
        while(no!=NULL){            
              if(strcmp(no->element->key,key)==0){  
                    return no->element;             
              }
              no=no->next;  
        }
        return NULL;
  }
```

When I run these tests it doesn't add the element to the list:

```
int testEmptyList() {
        struct list_t *list = list_create();
        int result = list != NULL && list_size(list) == 0;
        list_destroy(list);
        printf("Test empty list: %s\n",result?"pass":"not pass");
        return result;
}

int testAddHead() {
        int result;
        struct list_t *list = list_create();
        struct entry_t *entry = entry_create(strdup("abc"),data_create(5));
        memcpy(entry->value->data,"abc1",5);
        list_add(list,entry);
        result = list_get(list,"abc") == entry && 
        list_size(list) == 1;
        list_destroy(list);
        printf("Module list -> test add first: %s\n",result?"pass":"not pass");
        return result;
 }
```

So, what I want is put this code adding elements to the list. Thanks.

Comment: don't cast the return of malloc

Comment: Where's the code for `list_add`?

Comment: I don't mind if people want to down vote, but nobody learns from a down vote unless they're told why they're being down voted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int list_add(struct list_t *list, struct entry_t *entry){
        node_t *no = list->head;
        if(no==NULL){
             list->head=(node_t*) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
             list->head->element=entry_dup(entry);
             list->size=list->size+1;   
             return 0;
        }
        else{
             while(no->next!=NULL){
             no=no->next;
             }
        no->next=(node_t*) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        no->next->element=entry_dup(entry);
        no->next->next = NULL;
        list->size=list->size+1; 
        return 0;
        }
    return -1;
  }
```

The problem is that the previous node needs to know the address of the next one, via the pointer `next`. In your case, `no->next` will be equal to NULL (after the loop), so it's the last node. You never assign the `next` pointer of the last node to the new node, so it will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Several issues:

- You are destroying the list via `list_destroy` which can call `entry_destroy` on the entry added to the list before calling `list_get` which returns a pointer to (not a copy of) an entry.
- In `list_add` you call `malloc` to allocate space for a new node, however you don't set its `next` element to `NULL`. Since `malloc` does not guarantee that the memory allocated is wiped, the list may never end with a node that has its `next` element set to `NULL` resulting in spurious results.
- Your `else` branch in `list_add` guarantees `no` will be `NULL` (or the program will have crashed from a [segfault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) given earlier problems.) You probably want to terminate when `no->next` is `NULL` instead of when `no` is `NULL`. Also, this branch needs to assign the `next` element to `NULL` explicitly.